# Why is node's backtracking regex faster than RE2 in this example

Tags: node.js, regex, re2

I need to accept Regex from users--crazy, I know.  The Google RE2 regular expression parser is safer than PCRE-based ones since it doesn't use backtracking, thus preventing catastrophic backtracking, infinite loops and general mayhem.  It's purported to usually be faster.  In my test case, which just parses a syslog line, it's over **300% slower**.  Any ideas why?

I'm using Node v7.7.3 on Ubuntu.

The code in question:

```
const SYSLOG_LINE_REGEX = new RegExp([
    /(<[0-9]+>)?/, // 1 - optional priority
    /([a-z]{3})\s+/, // 2 - month
    /([0-9]{1,2})\s+/, // 3 - date
    /([0-9]{2}):/, // 4 - hours
    /([0-9]{2}):/, // 5 - minutes
    /([0-9]{2})/, // 6 - seconds
    /(\s+[\w.-]+)?\s+/, // 7 - host
    /([\w\-().0-9/]+)/, // 8 - process
    /(?:\[([a-z0-9-.]+)\])?:/, // 9 - optional pid
    /(.+)/ // 10  message
].map(regex => regex.source).join(''), 'i');
const parts = SYSLOG_LINE_REGEX.exec(log.trim());
```

**Update**:

- Using node module re2@1.4.1
- Using re2 C++ code dated 30 November 2016 that is included with the node-re2 package.
- I have the libre2-dev package version 20160501+dfsg-1 installed. Perhaps I should either update the sources under node-re2 or have it simply link to the system libraries.

Answer (score 1):

RE2 has linear **worst-case** complexity. Node.js's Irregexp engine has exponential **worst-case** complexity.

But! The worst-case behavior of an engine is a function not only of the regex but also of the input being tested. The regex `/(a+)+$/` is worst-case exponential in Node.js but if you match it against anything but `aaaaaaaaaa...a` it will run pretty quickly. The average-case match time of a regex is distinct from its worst-case complexity. The Node.js engine developers probably optimized the average-case complexity over the worst-case complexity.